# Почему форма Angular не валидируется?

Tags: angular

я создал форму, в ней есть DatePicker, использую https://materializecss.com/pickers.html, форма успешно работает, открывается и выбирается дата и так же вставляется в input, но проблема в том, что Angular не видит изменений и думает что Input все еще пустой и просит ввести дату. Но если использовать стандартный DatePicker от input type="date", то все работает.

```
<div class="input-field">
  <input
    type="text"
    id="preparationStartDate"
    formControlName="preparationStartDate"
    #preparationStartDate
    [ngClass]="{'invalid': form.get('preparationStartDate').invalid && form.get('preparationStartDate').touched}"
  >
  <label for="preparationStartDate">Начало</label>
</div>
```

Я новичок в Angular, подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить ошибку, чтобы после выбора даты через materialize datepicker, форма становилась валидной?

Comment: angular не может "не видеть изменений", это физически невозможно, значит ты что-то делаешь не так. Создай пример на stackblitz

Comment: попробуйте [отсюда](http://niceprogrammer.com/2018/02/17/angular-4-validation-errors/),
или добавте версию ангуляра и код компонента

Comment: @Gosha что тебе даст версия angular если поведение реактивных форм не менялось с 2.rc ?